# Silent .NET Wix Install Still Asks User to Confirm Installed Packages

Tags: .net, installation, bootstrapper, wix3

We have a requirement to bundle the .net 4.6.1 offline installer into our own Wix installer package. The .net component must be either silent or passive. We are not currently using Burn/bundle syntax, and I am strongly encouraged not to do so, as none of our other products use it. We are guaranteed to be installing into a Windows 7 environment.

I have managed to whittle all .Net prompts down to just asking the user to confirm installation, but even that is supposed to be hidden. I have tried both `/passive` and `/q` arguments in the bootstrapper product.xml, yet still it remains. From what I can see in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/commands-element-bootstrapper?view=vs-2019), I've done everything necessary to silence the .NET portion of the installer. I'm at a loss as to what else to try without completely changing our packaging approach (switching to Burn/bundles or writing a custom wix task that executes prior to installation).

From my products.xml (a good chunk taken from the SDK directory):

```xml
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="EmbeddedNET461">
  <!-- Defines list of files to be copied on build -->
  <PackageFiles CopyAllPackageFiles="false">
    <PackageFile Name="NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" PublicKey="..."/>
  </PackageFiles>
  ...
  <Commands Reboot="None">
    <!--Command for downlevel and future Operating Systems where netfx is not integrated within OS.-->
    <Command PackageFile="NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" Arguments=" /q /norestart /ChainingPackage Setup" EstimatedInstalledBytes="437362964" EstimatedInstallSeconds="600" EstimatedTempBytes="2095870765">
      <!-- These checks determine whether the package is to be installed -->
      <InstallConditions>
        <!-- This command is only for Samesite -->
        <BypassIf Property="InstallMode" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="HomeSite" />
        <!-- This indicates .NET Framework Full is already installed -->
        <BypassIf Property="DotNet461Full_Release" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="394254" />
        <!-- Block install if user does not have admin privileges -->
        <FailIf Property="AdminUser" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="false" String="AdminRequired" />
        <!-- Block install on less than Windows Vista -->
        <FailIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionLessThan" Value="6.0.0" String="InvalidPlatformWinNT" />
        <!-- Block install if the platform is IA-64 -->
        <FailIf Property="ProcessorArchitecture" Compare="ValueEqualTo" Value="IA64" String="InvalidPlatformArchitecture" />
      </InstallConditions>
      <ExitCodes>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Result="Success" />
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Result="SuccessReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Result="SuccessReboot" />
        <DefaultExitCode Result="Fail" FormatMessageFromSystem="false" String="GeneralFailure" />
      </ExitCodes>
    </Command>
  </Commands>
```

From my wixproj:

```xml
  <BootstrapperFile Include="Packages\DotNetFx461\EmbeddedNET461">
      <ProductName>.NET Installer 4.6.1</ProductName>
  </BootstrapperFile>
  ...
  ...
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Message Text="GenerateBootStrapper parameters:" />
    <Message Text="ApplicationFile: $(TargetFileName)" />
    <Message Text="OutputPath: $(OutputPath)" />
    <Message Text="Path: $(ProjectDir)\Bootstrapper" />
    <GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)" ApplicationName="App Name" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="Relative" CopyComponents="True" OutputPath="$(OutDir)" Path="$(ProjectDir)\Bootstrapper" />
  </Target>
```

It finds the installer just fine. It obeys the `/norestart`. It does not obey the `/q`. I still get the below on target systems.

[image]

**What am I missing to completely silence the .Net installation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That prompt comes from the Setup.exe bootstrapper, not the .NET Framework redistributable installer.

Comment: Do you have insight as to how to disable it? '/?' reveals no silent options on setup.exe.

Comment: It's not configurable. At least when it was introduced, the bootstrapper setup.exe didn't support the standard switches.

Answer (score 0):

I think the extra space may be what's causing this problem
Arguments=" /q /norestart /ChainingPackage Setup"
Right before the /q